# Layers not activated in Caffe

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning, caffe

I am using the pretrained AlexNet to classify a set of images. However, I find that many of the layers are not activated at all. For example, the output of the fc7 layer is all zero. I'm stuck at a dead end trying to figure out what is going wrong?

I have my training and testing data stored in separate .txt files in the following format

```
/path/to/foo1.jpg 0
/path/to/foo2.jpg 1
/path/to/foo3.jpg 0
/path/to/foo4.jpg 0
```

The code that I have written is

```
import numpy as np
import caffe 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import metrics

caffe.set_mode_cpu()
deploy = "path/to/bvlc_alexnet/deploy.prototxt" # Network to use
model = "path/to/bvlc_alexnet/bvlc_alexnet.caffemodel"

transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
transformer.set_mean('data', np.load('python/caffe/imagenet/ilsvrc_2012_mean.npy').mean(1).mean(1))
transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))
transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2,1,0))
transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255.0)

train_labels = []
test_labels = []

train_file = open("training.txt","r")
test_file = open("testing.txt","r")

for info in train_file:
    info = info[:-1]
    train_labels.append(int(info.split()[1]))

train_labels = np.array(train_labels)

for test_info in test_file:
    test_info = info[:-1] 
    test_labels.append(int(test_info.split()[1]))

test_labels = np.array(test_labels)
train_feats_fc7= []
test_feats_fc7= []

train_feats_fc8= []
test_feats_fc8= []

image_ctr = 1
for line in train_file:
    inpt = line.split()
    image_ctr+=1
    net.blobs["data"].data[...] = transformer.preprocess("data",caffe.io.load_image(inpt[0]))
    out = net.forward()
    feat_fc7= np.array(net.blobs["fc7"].data[0])
    print net.blobs["fc7"].data[0]
    feat_fc8= np.array(net.blobs["fc8"].data[0]) 
    train_feats_fc7.append(feat_fc7)
    train_feats_fc8.append(feat_fc8)

train_feats_fc7 = np.array(train_feats_fc7)
train_feats_fc8 = np.array(train_feats_fc8)
```

The fc7 layer contains only zeros.

Comment: Check this [`predict`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/python/caffe/classifier.py#L47) function, you could follow similar steps to extract fc7 feature.

Comment: You need to call caffe.Classifier to load the pretrained model.  Are you just trying to classify images or are you training something?  It looks like you want to fine-tune the pretrained model to classify using your classes (?)